# Probability that X is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, probability-theory

If X has the next density function:$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-|x|}}{2}$$ I need the probability of X is irrational.

I know that if you chosen a random number in the real numbers you get an irrational, but I don't know if that can help me. I think that the $P(X\ is\ an\ irrational)=1$, but I don't know how sustain it.

Thanks.

Comment: What’s the probability that $X$ is rational? Can you express it in terms of $f$?

Comment: Hint: The integral over a set of measure zero is zero.

Comment: Then the integral over a set of irrational is one? because is the complement of the set of the rationals?